# Chrome crashing when running Angular test cases using ng test

Tags: angular, maven, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

my Angular project is nested within maven. And I have configured pom.xml as:

```xml
<execution>
  <id>install node and npm</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
<execution>
  <id>npm install</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>npm</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
<execution>
  <id>npm run prod</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>npm</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <arguments>run test</arguments>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

but on running the build ie `npm run test`. The chrome crashes with the following Error Stack Trace

> Chrome 93.0.4577 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 29 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0       Chrome 93.0.4577 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 29 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0       ALERT: 'You have been logged out but please close the window manually if you are on Chrome.'
> [INFO] Chrome 93.0.4577 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 29 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.258 secs)
> [INFO] ALERT: 'You have been logged out but please close the window manually if        Chrome 93.0.4577 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 29 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.407 secs)
> [INFO] 20 09 2021 22:47:02.043:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome crashed.
> [INFO]  [34248:26472:0920/224656.598:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:46:56.599] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> [INFO] [34248:26472:0920/224656.599:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:46:56.599] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
> [INFO] [34248:26472:0920/224656.611:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [22:46:56.612] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.

Any clue what is going wrong here ?

Comment: Hello, have You found a solution ?